# multiple copyspecs in a single copytask in gradle (nested copyspecs)

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I have an ear file that will have root deployments (deploy configuration), lib deployments (earlibs configuration) and an additional custom utilJars configuration that I want to place in a `utilJars` folder at the root of the ear. I am aware that the first two configurations are automatically handled by the Ear task.

How can I add an additional `CopySpec` to the `Ear` task (or any `AbstractCopyTask` for that matter) to handle the third configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding of copy specs was erroneous. Instead of copyspecs existing side by side, they exist in a hierachy, as explained in [section 16.6.3](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files) of the gradle user guide.

thus additional copy specs may be 'nested' within the root specification of the task. These nested specs inherit the parent specs unless otherwise specified:

e.g. in the following spec, the root spec contains an `into`, `exclude` and `from` spec. in the `from` spec, there is a nested `include` spec. This spec does not overwrite anything from the root spec, and the root spec does not see it. The `into` spec does however overwrite the `from` copyspec and thus will copy everything from the configuration `'runtime'` into the folder `libs` but not anything from the `src/dist` folder.

```
task nestedSpecs(type: Copy) {
    into 'build/explodedWar'
    exclude '**/*staging*'
    from('src/dist') {
        include '**/*.html'
    }
    into('libs') {
        from configurations.runtime
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone else :)